# Madrid Connection

Tags: passports, international-travel, security, madrid

I will be connecting from Terminal 4 to 4S on an international flight, but on two separate airlines/itineraries. As in (example), I am flying into Terminal 4 with Delta from the USA, then connecting to another international flight outside the EU with a different airline. Will I need to go through security again, or can I go straight to the gate (carryons only, online checkin)? I will not have gone through a passport check in Madrid until I reach the gate, in theory.

Comment: Even if you can do an airside transfer, make sure that you have a passport that have a visa free entry in Spain, or have a valid Schengen visa. Otherwise, the first airline won't let you board the plane, since its not a connection.

Answer (score 5):

> Will I need to go through security again, or can I go straight to the gate (carryons only, online checkin)?

Most likely the answer is yes: you should be prepared to clear immigration, enter the Schengen area exit T4, take the bus to your terminal of departure and clear security again.

If you are lucky, they may be an airside connection (apparently there is a shuttle from T4 to T1) but that's hard to predict and you can't rely on it.

Please note that you MUST have proper credentials to enter the Schengen area. Otherwise the first airline (Delta) will deny you boarding and you won't make it to Madrid in the first place.

Comment: The OP says they are connecting from T4 to T4S, so they don't leave T4 they just get on the free shuttle train for T4S.